# Parameter 'dispatch' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have recently changed my JS based project to TypeScript. I am getting following lint issue and I don't know what is the type of `dispatch`. I am wondering what it is?

[image]

I know I am able to tell tslint to ignore this checking by `"noImplicitAny": false` in tsconfig file. However, I am not sure this is good way to do that or not.

Comment: `dispatch` is a function

Comment: @Tony, ah, you are right. Thanks. How to get rid of the error message?

Comment: `(dispatch: Dispatch<S>) =>` I think? I don't use TypeScript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dispatch is [defined](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1fc00061a829e44e58e19a4001c754ef2b0ba1bc/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L29) in `@types/react-redux` as

```
type Dispatch<S> = Redux.Dispatch<S>;
```

When I encountered this error message in the past, I simply had to install the [`@types/react-redux`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-redux) package.

You will likely find that many projects do not contain typings files. Luckily, the `@types` packages on NPM exist. They are maintained by the community at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I confirm I have `"@types/react-redux": "^5.0.16",` under my `devDependencies` and get above error. However, `DefinitelyTyped` is new to me. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: You might be able to import the `Dispatch` type alongside `connect` on line 8, and update the underlined text on 161 with `dispatch: Dispatch`.

Comment: This is nice trick but linter is asking to specify a generic for Dispatch. If I give it Dispatch<string> the it works but I am not sure what the generic should be.

Comment: It looks like [the typings use](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1fc00061a829e44e58e19a4001c754ef2b0ba1bc/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L163-L165) `Dispatch<any>` when specifying what a `mapDispatchToProps` function may be. It might be better to just declare the type of `mapDispatchToProps` as `MapDispatchToPropsFunction`, and allow the compiler to infer the type of `dispatch`.

Comment: `MapDispatchToPropsFunction` is a generic with `TDispatchProps` and `TOwnProps`, which correspond to the `mapDispatchToProps` return type and the component's props, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helps. After a quick investigation, I think I go with `Dispatch<any>`.

Answer (score 26):

For better clarity, following should be the code snippet.

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

//..... code
//..... code

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
    // assignment here
});
```